# Who would be interested in playing Among Us with fellow members of Arqade?

Tags: discussion, community-event

If you hadn't noticed, [among-us](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/among-us) is a very popular game at the moment, but it is best played with friends or premade groups. Would anyone be interested in joining in playing together? Preferably, we would use the Arqade unofficial discord server for voice chat, and we would need at least 6 people to play, but preferably 10. If we have more, we could do multiple sessions/lobbies or rotate people in depending on availability.

Comment: missed opportunity for title to be "Who among us would be interested..."

Answer (score 5):

I would! I would say, open a chat just for among us and plan games in there! (Sorry, I don't use discord). Arqade chat would be better because people could join it without discord.

I'mma go make the chat now.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115056/arqade-among-us

Comment: Discord is suggested because of the voice chat, which Arqade chat lacks.

Comment: Voice is nice, but not necessarily required and I like the idea of at least using our chat system here for coordinating events

Answer (score 5):

I'm down.

I made a simple poll for all of you to fill in aat what time and what day of the week you're available in general, so that we avoid sending each other messages without actually getting a group together.

Here's the link: https://doodle.com/poll/8b69nrftnp266atr

It says which timezone it displays, so take that into account.